# Sort a list of dictionary provided an order

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I've a list

```
order = [8, 7, 5, 9, 10, 11]
```

and a list of dictionaries

```
list_of_dct = [{'value':11}, {'value':8}, {'value':5}, {'value':7}, {'value':10}, {'value':9}]
```

I want to sort this `list_of_dct` by the order given in `order` list, i.e. the output should be the following:

```
list_of_dct = [{'value':8}, {'value':7}, {'value':5}, {'value':9}, {'value':10}, {'value':11}]
```

I know how to sort by a given `key`, but not when an order is already given. How can I sort it?

PS: I already have an O(n^2) solution. Looking for a better solution.

Comment: Is the key `value` static for all the dict in the list or is it just a placeholder? Also, does `order` list contain all the items present in the dict i.e. duplicates as well?

Comment: Rather than performing a general sort, it would be more efficient to build a `dict` containing the values as keys, then just extract the entries in order from that.  Questions:  (1) Is every value in `order` known to exist as a value in `list_of_dct`?  (2) Can the same value occur more than once in `list_of_dct`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use index of the `order` list to sort-Just try if every dictionary has one value and you want sorting by that value-

```
sorted(list_of_dct,key=lambda x:order.index(x.values()[0]))
```

But if you have multiple values for one key then change the index (i.e `[0]`) on which you will sort.

Answer (score 3):

Make a mapping of 8 to 0, 7 to 1, ..., 11 to 5 using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> order = [8,7,5,9,10,11]
>>> list_of_dct = [{'value':11}, {'value':8}, {'value':5},
                   {'value':7}, {'value':10}, {'value':9}]
>>> sort_keys = {item: i for i, item in enumerate(order)}
>>> sort_keys
{5: 2, 7: 1, 8: 0, 9: 3, 10: 4, 11: 5}
```

And use it as a sorting key:

```
>>> list_of_dct.sort(key=lambda d: sort_keys.get(d['value'], len(sort_keys)))
>>> list_of_dct
[{'value': 8}, {'value': 7}, {'value': 5}, {'value': 9},
 {'value': 10}, {'value': 11}]
```

use `sort_keys.get(..)` instead of `sort_keys[..]` to prevent `KeyError` in case of value is misisng in `order`.

Comment: Upvoted it because of the dict lookup which only 0(1) complexity.